# document.getElementById('keylink').innerHTML = '<a ></a>'; not working in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

As you can see from the title that code not working in IE but working in other browsers also if I use like that

```
document.getElementById('keylink').innerHTML = '<p>hi</p>';
```

It's working so there is problem in `<a>` and `innerHTML` please give me some solution on that

Comment: Marking to close as "Not a real question". The title and the body disagree, no context is provided, and "not working" is an insufficient description of the problem. You need to provide a test case that actually demonstrates the problem, tell us what error messages are reported, tell us where it does work (which is presumably somewhere since you added the 'in ie' qualifier), and tell us which versions of ie you are testing with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE won't identify blank anchors.. try something like this:

```
document.getElementById('keylink').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="return false;">hi</a>';
```

To create "dummy" link that doesn't do anything when clicked but still looks like a link.

Comment: document.getElementById('keylink').innerHTML = '<a id="keylink"  OnMouseOver="javascript:fun()" style="color:Aqua;font-size : medium" > Enter</a>'; still not working

Comment: @VbPatel because you don't have `href` attribute - add this like in my example and it will work.

Comment: @VbPatel please edit your question and add the exact code you're using. Let me know in comment here after you do that.